# How do i add all the value of this array

Tags: karate

This might be very stupid question but can someone tell me how to sum the following array in karate

simple array [18, 190, 220, 0]

something like this ?

- def response = [18, 190, 220, 0]

And assert response == 428

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Refer loops: https://github.com/intuit/karate#json-transforms

```
* def array = [18, 190, 220, 0]
* def result = 0
* def fun = function(x){ var temp = karate.get('result'); karate.set('result', temp + x )}
* karate.forEach(array, fun)
* match result == 428
```

If the above looks too scary, you can always define it as a re-usable function, or you can use a Java utility you write: https://github.com/intuit/karate#commonly-needed-utilities

Comment: Thank you @peter, this works out, i was actually trying with reduce method and that didnt work

Comment: for those who havn't upgraded their Karate version to 0.9.4 it will be * eval karate.forEach(array, fun)